# Help! I can no longer access photos from my gallery when trying to send a picture

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-4, photos, gallery

I have a Samsung S4.
when I'm trying to attach a photo to an MMS I used to get an option of accessing the photo via galary or Samsung link. Usually I selected gallery. This time I accidentally clicked Samsung link and now I can't access pics to send via gallery it only takes me straight to Samsung link.

**My question is how do I access pics to send via gallery not Samsung link?**

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the default application settings in settings > apps > [your app] > "launch by default"

Comment: or you can manually select the image from gallery and share it via MMS.